# ZF2 load different view based on domain

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework3

I have an application where I want to load some different views based on a different domain using the existing modules in my app, how can I accomplish that in my routes?

I only want to change my layout so my vriews should be involved only.

Comment: Please don´t forget to accept one answer if it was helpful. Other readers will appreciate it, facing the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

**1st Part**

In ZF2 you can change layouts in ActionControllers:

```
public function indexAction () 
{
     $this->layout('layout/customLayout');

     return $viewModel;
}
```

Therefore you have to add an entry in module.config.php (view_manager section):

```
//... configs
'view_manager' => array(
    // other configs...
    'template_map' => array(
        'layout/layout' => 'path to default layout',
        'layout/customLayout' => 'path to custom layout',
    ),
),
```

**2nd Part**

You have 2 domains pointing to the same source code directory (your zf2-project) on your server:

- http://domain1.com/index
- http://domain2.com/index

Via web server config (nginx, apache), both requests will be routed to an IndexController (e.g. in Application module). By default routes do not depend on the server's name (hostname).  Or better said: its domain. FYI, you can configure routes for specific hostname, but that would be off-topic ;) The web server changes some environment variables of PHP, e.g. `$_SERVER` depending on the calling domain. In this php array you can detect details like the current server name.
Detect this in Application\Controller\IndexController:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $serverName = $this->getRequest()->getServer('SERVER_NAME'); 
    $layout = ($serverName == 'domain2.com') ? 'layout/customLayout' : 'layout/layout';
    $this->layout($layout);
    // other stuff
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a plan, but then other domains need their own controllers ?

Comment: In general, the whole project is independent of the domain from which your php code is called through the webserver. If you have e.g. 2 domains routing in the same zf2 project, you can detect domains and decide which layout to load.

Comment: But that means I need a different controllerAction for it ? Some example there would be nice as well as I'm confused about it.

Comment: That sounds like a vert good plan, I thought that was not "valid", ice to see it is!. But your opinion about the different routes is discussable. I might need that I need to load another controller once for some domain when domain2.com/foo2 is loaded instead of the default /foo How would that be done in a proper way using the views as well ? I see a 3rd version ;) Thanks so far!

Comment: Sorry, that is confusing me ;) domain2.com/foo2, domain1.com/foo, depending on route config, again the domain can be neglected. Usually these routes would end up Foo2Controller::indexAction() and FooController::indexAction(). Or do you mean, /foo2 and /foo are routed in the same controller actions? It really depends on route config and what you want in detail.

Comment: If you want to have one route on the 2 domains like d1.com/foo and d2.com/foo and they should go to different Controllers: you can configure the routing depending on 'hostname', then assign different controllers, that should be invoked. Please see: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html

Comment: I found that in the past indeed. Thanks for verifying!

Answer (score 0):

I do that kind of stuff in my Modules (Module.php). In the bootstrap method I trigger the setLayout-Method first. But first of all I need my layouts set in the template_map. Then I can change the layout based on the route, controller, host etc. I build my routes after a specific pattern in order to group them logically. ;)

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $app = $e->getParam('application');

    $app->getEventManager()->attach(
        'dispatch', array(
        $this,
        'setLayout'
    ));
}
public function setLayout(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $matches = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $routeName = $matches->getMatchedRouteName();
    $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
    $serverHost = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
   # ... Implement your application logic ...use Switch or sth. ...# 
    e->getTarget()->layout('layout/layout'); // <-- based on host and your logic
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, for neglecting it! It is inside a Module.php